# Better way to make a multilingual site?

Tags: javascript, multilingual

So I'm working on my first website and I have a bad feeling that the way I'm making it multilingual will make it impossible for search-engines to index it, as it uses javascript.

The way it works is as such. The HTML tags don't have any text in them, but have a "data-lang" attribute with a key in it. The client has a different dictionary for every language, and all share the same keys. I have a simple script that simply checks the keys for the current language and fills in the tags with the values of those keys. When you change language, the current language simply changes and it does the process again.

Of course, this is all dynamic. The advantage is that there's no need to reload the page, which would be nice to keep, though not absolutely necessary.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Multilingual or not, if the content is pure air, you're on the dark side of the force. If you construct your page like in PHP with nice and working links-to-pages (like for JS disabled crawlers) and than you push your content from those pages AJAXynamically it does not matters if it's multilingual or not again. But in that case you're using wisely the force. (Just make sure your army of content is there once they come!)

Comment: follow the google guidelines for ajax driven pages.